# Input from Spectrum js for polymer data binding

Tags: polymer, spectrumjs

I am looking to dynamically insert a spectrum input field to have a more customized color picker in my template. The issue I've encountered is that the object I want to bind data to is null from inside of spectrum functions. I'm wondering what the best way to go about integrating spectrum into a polymer template is.

As you will see, when editMode is initiated, spectrum is instantiated and the div is inserted into the HTML. On change(), I want to take whatever color is selected and bind it to the *document* object. My console.log returns that the *document* is indeed null. Inside of the editMode function, before going into spectrum, *document* is a polymer object as expected. I tried making *document* a global var but that doesn't make a difference because it's no longer the binded object so I can't access any of its properties, save it, etc.

Does spectrum need to be a custom element? Any insight?

```
    <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'image-view',
    behaviors: [Test.LayoutBehavior],
    properties: {

      /**
         * @doctype Image
         */
      document: {
        type: Object,
        observer: '_documentChanged'
      },
      edit: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    },

    _canEdit: function(doc) {
      return doc && doc.type !== 'Root' && this.hasPermission(doc, 'Write');
    },
    _editMode: function() {
      this.edit = true;

      $(".spectrum-div").html(
        "<label>Brand Text Color</label><input type='text' id='full'/>"
      );

      $("#full").spectrum({
        color: "#ECC",
        showInput: true,
        className: "full-spectrum",
        showInitial: true,
        showPalette: true,
        showSelectionPalette: true,
        maxSelectionSize: 10,
        preferredFormat: "hex",

        move: function (color) {

        },
        show: function () {

        },
        beforeShow: function () {

        },
        hide: function () {

        },
        change: function(color) {

          if (this.document != null) {
            console.log('THIS DOCUMENT IS NOT NULL');
            console.log(this.document.properties["image:brand_text_color"]);
          } else console.log('Sorry, document is null.');

          var col = color.toHexString();
          //$("#brand-text-color").val(col);
          //document.getElementById("brand-text-color").value = col;
          this.document.properties["image:brand_text_color"] = col;

        },

        palette: [
            ["rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(67, 67, 67)", "rgb(102, 102, 102)",
            "rgb(204, 204, 204)", "rgb(217, 217, 217)","rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
            ["rgb(152, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 153, 0)", "rgb(255, 255, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
            "rgb(0, 255, 255)", "rgb(74, 134, 232)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)", "rgb(153, 0, 255)", "rgb(255, 0, 255)"], 
            ["rgb(230, 184, 175)", "rgb(244, 204, 204)", "rgb(252, 229, 205)", "rgb(255, 242, 204)", "rgb(217, 234, 211)", 
            "rgb(208, 224, 227)", "rgb(201, 218, 248)", "rgb(207, 226, 243)", "rgb(217, 210, 233)", "rgb(234, 209, 220)", 
            "rgb(221, 126, 107)", "rgb(234, 153, 153)", "rgb(249, 203, 156)", "rgb(255, 229, 153)", "rgb(182, 215, 168)", 
            "rgb(162, 196, 201)", "rgb(164, 194, 244)", "rgb(159, 197, 232)", "rgb(180, 167, 214)", "rgb(213, 166, 189)", 
            "rgb(204, 65, 37)", "rgb(224, 102, 102)", "rgb(246, 178, 107)", "rgb(255, 217, 102)", "rgb(147, 196, 125)", 
            "rgb(118, 165, 175)", "rgb(109, 158, 235)", "rgb(111, 168, 220)", "rgb(142, 124, 195)", "rgb(194, 123, 160)",
            "rgb(166, 28, 0)", "rgb(204, 0, 0)", "rgb(230, 145, 56)", "rgb(241, 194, 50)", "rgb(106, 168, 79)",
            "rgb(69, 129, 142)", "rgb(60, 120, 216)", "rgb(61, 133, 198)", "rgb(103, 78, 167)", "rgb(166, 77, 121)",
            "rgb(91, 15, 0)", "rgb(102, 0, 0)", "rgb(120, 63, 4)", "rgb(127, 96, 0)", "rgb(39, 78, 19)", 
            "rgb(12, 52, 61)", "rgb(28, 69, 135)", "rgb(7, 55, 99)", "rgb(32, 18, 77)", "rgb(76, 17, 48)"]
        ]
      });
    },



    _documentChanged: function() {
      if (this.document) {
        this.edit = false;
      }
    },
    _isAdmin: function(user) {
      return user.isAdministrator;
    }
  });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can place the input field into your element's local DOM, and hide it when not in `edit` mode:

```
<label hidden$="[[!edit]]" for="full">Brand Text Color</label>
<iron-input bind-value="{{document.prop}}">
    <input hidden$="[[!edit]]" type="text" id="full"/>
</iron-input>
```

(Note that I also added an iron-input, since you will need value-binding below.)

That way you can access it from JavaScript by id, via `this.$.full`.

Finally, you can initialize spectrum from Polymer's `attached` callback:

```
Polymer({
    properties: {
        document: {
            type: Object,
            // initialize with an object holding all required keys, 
            // for proper change notification
            value: function() {
                return {
                    // document properties here
                    prop: null
                };
            },
            observer: '_syncDocument'
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
    attached() {
        $(this.$.full).spectrum({
            ...
        });
    },
    _syncDocument(newValue) {
        // window.document[???] = newValue.prop;
    }
    ...
});
```

Now I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the document. Is it the window.document? In that case you'd need to sync your element.document.value to window.document.[propertyName] manually, in an observer on your element.document.

PS: Don't forget to include iron-input, or work around my quick implementation with something else.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have an empty div where the spectrum input will be inserted and a hidden input field already with the binding (it's a custom input element). You will see in the above code that I commented out a couple lines where I try to take the selected color, convert it to a HEX string, and then call the field.val(hexvalue). On document.save, the value doesn't seem to persist though. I'm going to try to write  a similar _syncDocument function now and see if the problem is just syncing element.document to the global document